# CakePHP ACL disable automatic ARO creation

Tags: cakephp, acl

I (finally) got ACL to work properly, based on group permissions. However when I create a new user (Users/add) it automagically.. I mean.. autoinconveniently creates a User ARO.. 
While this is not really a big problem, I would like my ARO table to stay as clean as possible. Just my groups.

**How do I disable the automatic creation of a User ARO object when creating a new user through CRUD?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i had the same problem and, like you, i said to myself "its not a big deal as long as it's working"... but when i started to have more and more users and when i added new groups, i found that ACL was not working correctly.. If you're using a group-based permissions, you MUST ONLY have groups in your AROS table.

Brief, [the documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/#x11-2-4-1-Group-only-ACL-1646) says that you need to add the `bindNode()` in your Users model if you want a group-based ACL, but what they don't tell you is that for group-based permissions your User model doesn't have to implement the requester behavior and you don't need the parentNode() neither. Remove those two and it should be ok.

I added a note on the documentation, i hope it gets published :)

Good Luck

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! With hindsight, it kinda makes sense to remove the "acts as requester". I hope it gets published too.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. Wow the Cake documentation is really lacking in quite a few areas - this is not explained clearly at all.